# Is this possible for SQL Primary Key? (Rank on list)

Tags: mysql, sql

When I delete a row and create a new one, the primary key doesn't start over at 1, but at 2. I guess that's how it was meant to work when I made it auto_increment. But is it possible to update the primary key whenever a row above it is deleted and all rows under that.

If that isn't possible can I just make another column called rank and make it update depending on what order the rows are in?

Comment: If you tried hard enough, sure, but why bother?

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to care about what the primary keys id is, all that matters is that it's unique. We use sort queries and stuff to worry about order if that's your issue.

If you have code that always requires the primary key to be in the range of 1..number_of_rows with no gaps there is a problem with the design of your application.

You should not make a column called rank, its easy just to do a `SELECT * FROM things ORDER BY some_column;`

The difference to this is if you need calculated values to sort your table. E.g., an orders total. In order for you to sort orders by their total they need a calculated value on the table. The query is still simple as the one I mentioned.